# Наиболее часто встречающееся значение, MDX

Tags: sql-server, olap

Возникла необходимость посчитать в мембере наиболее часто встречающееся выражение определенной меры. Посчитать нужно именно в мембере, т.к. период может быть разным и значение соответственно должно пересчитываться.

Если следующий код

```
select [Measures].[Umsatz VK Brutto CM] on 0,
non empty   (
            [Datum].[Monat Key Name].&[201601],
            [Artikel].[BasVanr Char Name].children,
            [Hypermarkt].[SBWID].&[67005901]
            ) on 1
from [GlobusUser]
```

возвращает

```
 201601 - A - GM67005901 - 10 штук
 201601 - B - GM67005901 - 20 штук
 201601 - C - GM67005901 - 30 штук
 201601 - D - GM67005901 - 30 штук
 201601 - E - GM67005901 - 40 штук
```

то мембер должен вернуть значение 30

Comment: Могу предложить отсортировать подвыборкой по частоте встречание через count, и поставть топ `select top 1  x, count(*) from ( ...) group by x order by 2 desc`

Comment: Нужен мембер в мдх, а не транзакт sql

Answer (score 0):

Этот наиболее часто встречающийся член распределения называется *мода*.
На примере велозавода

```
Create MEMBER CurrentCube.[Measures].[Mode Price] AS
   iif( IsEmpty( [Measures].[Reseller Transaction Count] ),
       null,
       TopCount( [Price].[Price].[Price].MEMBERS,
           1,
           [Measures].[Reseller Transaction Count]
       ).Item(0).MemberValue
   )
```

Здесь дополнительно создается изменение цен - `Price`, без него оно не работает.
Если без доп измерений - есть [метод вызова Excel функций в MDX](http://blogs.adatis.co.uk/jeremykashel/post/Mean-Median-and-Mode-in-MDX), а там есть функция поиска моды.